# What types of files can CLIPS open

Tags: file-io, clips

I am working on developing an expert system using CLIPS. For the case at hand I need to read data from a excel file. How do I do that? Or what solutions do you propose? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the open command to open a file for reading in either text or binary mode. If you opened a xlsx file in binary mode, you could use the get-char function to retrieve individual characters from the file. There's no built-in functionality for parsing a xlsx file, so you'd have to add code to do the parsing and create appropriate CLIPS values from the data. If possible, it would be easier to save your excel file as tab-delimited text. If each cell is a valid CLIPS token, then you can use the read function to retrieve the cell values. If each cell is not a valid CLIPS token (for example, a cell representing a string that has spaces but lacks quotation marks at the beginning and end), then you need to use the readline function to grab an entire row of data and then use some of the string functions to locate the tabs and split the string into valid tokens.

Comment: What about JESS ? Because searching the internet, it seems that jess can read excel files, but I am not sure.

Comment: You have access to Java from Jess so all you need to do is find a library that will read excel files. Search for "java excel library" and you'll find several.